# How to transfer an UIImage object to my Static Library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, static-libraries

I'm creating a Static Library for several iOS applications of my company. I almost completed it, but there is an issue with the image resources.

My Static Library need an Image which should be provided by each application, and I know we can transfer resources through a Bundle file, but it seems it would be too complex to using my Static Library, I was wondering If I can expose a class method like:

```
+(void)setLogoImage:(UIImage *)image;
```

But it not work, only nil received.

Some thing must missed, how can I do it? thanks in advance.

Comment: A class method is probably not the best approach because it will need to be backed by a class-wide static variable. Consider delegation.

Comment: That isn't enough information to answer the question.  There is no reason why that would not work at all, so the error is elsewhere.

Comment: @Jef  thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @trojanfoe your may be right, must be error  some where else